# Looking for php script to sort phone numbers (xxx-xxx-xxxx) in separate rows

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for php array script so i can write my phone numbers list in separate rows like 
xxx-xxx-0001 in first line 
xxx-xxx-0002 in second line 
xxx-xxx-0003 in third line 
on my website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11);
sort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
echo $numbers[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add phone format xxx-xxx-xxxx instead of numbers but its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$numbers = array(416-224-0001,416-224-0002,416-224-0003);
sort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
echo $numbers[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

that's what i tried , please let me know if i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to sort purely based on the last 4 digits (last digits after the hyphen:

```
   function cmp($a, $b) {

   if ($a == $b) {//ptobably wont apply here
       return 0;
   }

   $explodedA = explode('-', $a);
   $explodedB = explode('-', $b);
   $lastBitA = $explodedA[count($explodedA) - 1];//get the last section for the compare
   $lastBitB = $explodedB[count($explodedB) - 1];


   if ($lastBitA == $lastBitB) { 
      return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
   }

   return ($lastBitA < $lastBitB) ? -1 : 1;
}

$numbers = array('777-999-0002','416-224-0003','416-224-0001','776-244-0008');
usort($numbers, "cmp");

print_r($numbers);
```

//returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 416-224-0001
    [1] => 777-999-0002
    [2] => 416-224-0003
    [3] => 776-244-0008
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Sorry still not working for some reason , could you please check one more time for me ... thanks